# Compiling a MEX file using object files in another folder

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm writing some MATLAB code, and I want to use some optimized C routines.  I have the C source code, and it works just fine.  I've created a MEX file and am capable of compiling it provided that it is in the same folder as the optimized C routines.  However, I want to be able to distribute this code to others on various platforms.  Since MEX files are binaries, each individual must (likely) recompile on their own machines.  That is fine, but I want to make the process as painless as possible.

Currently, if all of the files are in the same directory, then calling something like

```
mex mexfile.c other1.o other2.o other3.o
```

from that directory works just fine as you would expect.  For organizational purposes, however, I'd like for the C code to be in its own (sub)directory, say `code`.  Unfortunately, if I structure things like this, the `mex` command errors out (the errors differ based on the different things that I've tried).  I've tried things like

```
mex mexfile.c code/other1.o code/other2.o code/other3.o
```

and the `-Ipathname` and `-Lfolder` options on the `mex` command, but these haven't worked for me.  I would think that there has to be a simple way to do what I'm wanting to do, but I just can't find the appropriate documentation or figure it out myself.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please write the error message of the mex command.

Comment: I was regenerating the errors, per request; and I stumbled on the solution.  This is my first post to Stack Overflow, and I'm not sure how I should provide the solution to my own question.

Comment: Great.  Thanks.  I guess scrolling down a few lines would have answered that question, eh?

Comment: I've edited the post to provide the answer because users "with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking".  If this is discouraged, please let me know so that it can be fixed (after 8 hours).

Answer (score 1):

[OP's solution converted to answer below]

In the setup given above, using the following command works as desired for me:

```
mex -Icode mexfile.c code/other1.o code/other2.o code/other3.o
```

I stumbled across this solution while regenerating error messages.

I'm guessing that this is just the appropriate syntax for the `-Ipathname` option to the `mex` command, but I can't find documentation to support this conclusion.  If anyone else can provide a link to actual documentation, that would certainly be better than a potential solution that just happened to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use something along the lines of

```
emlc -I './somedir/' -o sourcefilemex -T mex sourcefile
```

By changing the -T argument you can generate mex code or embeddable C. That's handy.